# How can to do the inverse of explode modifier in Blender

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

How can to do the inverse of explode modifier in Blender
[like the text "CHRIS MACARI" at the beginning in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xX4Pxiwti4E)

Here is a GIF of this section
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You may do it using the ***Video Sequence Editor***.
[image]

Go to the *Video Sequence Editor* window (Sequencer) and add the scene animation strip to it (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>-->*Scene*-->*Scene*). Check the ***Backwards*** checkbox in the *Filter* panel of the *properties shelf* (press <kbd>N</kbd> being in the *Video Sequence Editor* window). 
[image]

Press the ***Image Preview*** button to see the preview of your animation. Render animation with <kbd>F12</kbd>.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I made this addon:

[How to reverse an animation?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82361/how-to-reverse-an-animation)

(It contains details on excatly how to do a reverse explosion)

It allows much greater control than simply running the explosion backwards as seen above, although that can be useful.