# How do you reverse physics simulations?

Tags: animation, physics, rigid-body-simulation, force-fields

I have a bunch of rigid-body objects that get moved by a force field. I want to reverse the physics simulation so that it plays backwards while other animations, like the camera movement and animated textures, still play back forwards. Is there a way to maybe reverse a Bake of the physics?
TIA

Comment: you can "reverse" a force field by multiplying the strength with -1. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 4):

A solution would be to bake to keyframes then reverse the animation: Select the object(s) then *Object > Rigid Body > Bake to Keyframes*, then in the *Dope Sheet* select all the keyframes and press <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>-1</kbd>:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a duplicate of a question that I asked and answered a while ago.

[How to reverse an animation?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82361/how-to-reverse-an-animation)

But basically I made an addon that does exactly what you want. Automatically bakes to keyframes, and reverses the animation. It can be found here:

https://github.com/FreddieRa/BlenderAddons/blob/master/AutoReverse.py

Comment: Your addon seems to be outdated, it's not working anymore in version 3.0.1